# Count how many rows it takes to reach certain query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a pretty simple query,

```
$query3 = $db->query("SELECT * FROM mybb_ranks WHERE id='1' ORDER by points DESC");
```

And what it'll return is a database of people who are registered and ranked. Since players points can be randomly changing due to matches, we determine the rank # by assigning it once the value is fetched in a way like this:

```
$i = 1;
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query5))

 {
echo "$row[player]'s rank is $i";
           $i++;

 }
```

As you can see, it orders the player's by their points, but determines the rank # from a variable that adds after displaying every rank. However, in each of the user profiles, I would like to display their rank as well. This is a bit more difficult, because I need a certain way to count the amount of rows the query has to go through in order to get to the certain player. So for instance, if PlayerB is ranked at #5, I would need a way to display that on his own profile. For this to happen, I imagine the query would need to be altered to be able to count each individual row (4 rows) before it reaches the certain player on the 5th row. I was wondering, how would I go about this?

Comment: how about running the while loop but then only echo when it equals that persons id

Comment: @MichaelStClair I ended up doing that, it works but I feel like it's not very efficient. Thanks for the tip! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE mybb_ranks 
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT
 player,
 @rank:=@rank+1 as current_rank
FROM mybb_ranks 
WHERE id='1'
ORDER BY points DESC
) AS t
ON mybb_ranks.player = t.player
SET mybb_ranks.rank = t.current_rank
```

That means you have to create additional column `rank` in your `mybb_ranks` table.

This query will update the **rank** of user each time you generate your ranks list.

So when you need to show user's rank in his profile page you just request it from the table:

```
SELECT rank 
FROM mybb_ranks
WHERE player = :player_id
```

if you want it more dynamic, you can run this UPDATE query every time when you generate your player profile page, right before `SELECT rank`.

Comment: Could you add a few words to explain **how** this solves the problem?

Comment: To be honest, I don't even understand how this could possibly solve my problem. Very confusing.